# Is it possible to have several actions for a single keycode in XKB keymap?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

In XKB (X keyboard extension), it seems to me only one Action max is possible for any keysym:

> There is zero or one key action associated with each keysym bound to each key.
> https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XkbKeyAction.3.xhtml

On the other hand, multiple keysyms per a keycode are supported by `libxkbcommon` as XKB extention:
[◆ xkb_state_key_get_syms()](https://xkbcommon.github.io/libxkbcommon/doc/current/group__state.html#ga47311e7268935dd2fe3e6ef057a82cb0)

Can this or any other approach be utilized to effectively have multiple actions for a keycode press?
Something like this (which probably is a bad syntax as it has multiple actions for a single keysym):

```
   xkb_symbols {
       key <LWIN> { [ Super_L ] };
       modifier_map Mod3 { Super_L };
   }

   xkb_compatibility {
       interpret Super_L { action = SetGroup(group=1); };
       interpret Super_L { action = SetMods(modifiers=Mod3); };
   }
```

So that pressing the `LWIN` key would switch the group and at the same time set a modifier.

The roots of the question is here:
[[Help] Switching layout temporary while modifier is held](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues/416)
We are trying to find a way on XKB level to have different layout for a key combinations with modifiers (shortcuts).